# Probability in moving from state $\lvert1\rangle$ to $\lvert2\rangle $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

The system is $|1\rangle$ at time $t = 0$, while $|2\rangle$ at time $t$. 
The base is orthonormal $\left\{|1\rangle, |2\rangle\right\}$. Epsilon and delta are positive constants, which have some energy unit. The system is:
$$
\hat{H} = \epsilon\left(-1|1\rangle\langle1|+|2\rangle\langle2|\right)+\delta\left(|1\rangle\langle2|+|2\rangle\langle1|\right)
$$

What is the probability of moving from state $|1\rangle$ into the state $|2\rangle$?

Comment: Since it tells you it's in state 2 at time t, I'd say 100% ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an outline of what you have to do:

- You need to find the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. Write $\hat H$ as a $2\times 2$ matrix in the $\{|1\rangle,|2\rangle\}$ basis and diagonalize it, i.e. find its eigenvalues $E_1,E_2$ and the corresponding eigenvectors $|E_1\rangle, |E_2\rangle$.
- You can then decompose the initial state $|\psi\rangle$, $|1\rangle$ in your case, in terms of $|E_1\rangle$ and $|E_2\rangle$. The result will be something like this:

$|\psi(t=0)\rangle = c_1|E_1\rangle+c_2|E_2\rangle$

- The time evolve state will then be given by:

$|\psi(t)\rangle = c_1e^{iE_1t/\hbar}|E_1\rangle + c_2e^{iE_2t/\hbar}|E_2\rangle$

- Find the probability that the system is in state $|2\rangle$ at time $t$ by calculating the mod square of the scalar product:

$P_{1\to 2}(t) = |\langle 2|\psi(t)\rangle|^2$

I can clarify any step if you don't know exactly what to do.

Comment: **Can we assume that c1 = 0 at time t?** I think we can assume at least that c2 = 0 when t = 0.

Comment: No. As the Hamiltonian is not diagonal in the $\{|1\rangle,|2\rangle\}$-basis, its eigenstate will be different from $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ and thus $c_1\ne 0$ and $c_2\ne 0$!